in Python why do I get "name 'a' is not defined" even though I have defined it as global?
Here is example code:
async def main():

    a = 10
    async def test():
        global a
        a +=2
        print(a)
    
    await test()
    
asyncio.run(main())

and the resulting error:
a +=2
^
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

why are you doing this instead of just passing a as a parameter?

It's not global if you declare it inside main

@Elerium115 this is just a test to understand the way global variables are working...

In 99% of the cases you don't need global variables. Global variables lead to bad code and are prone to bugs if not used properly. So instead of learning something that you most likely don't need I'd suggest you learn about something more useful. For example do you know about classes and encapsulation? Extremely useful, learn that if you don;t know about it yet.

Because in this example a isn't a global variable. Its in the local space of the main function. For it to be global a needs to be completely outside everything
Also on another note, adding to global variables concurrently without any form of locking on the variable is a bad idea as it can lead to unexpected results
